# How to connect to a Google account from shell

Tags: shell, gmail, wget, google-account

I would like to connect from shell to a Google account in order to simulate navigation from this account with something like *wget*.
I have tried this command :

```
wget -T 3 -t 1 -q --secure-protocol=TLSv1  --no-check-certificate  --user=$username --password=$password https://mail.google.com/mail/feed0/atom -O -
```

But I don't manage to validate the connection...
Maybe with curl ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Login/password is insecure and not supported anymore.
You need at least an "[application-specific password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270)" or better [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know. I am studying your solutions but for my script, using a cookie is more easy (it is just to test something for educational purpose).